# How to separate data in multiple sheets in excel using java poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a java code that retrieves the data from the database and copies them to an excel sheet then creates a file,
but all the retrieval data are shown in 1 sheet my problem is to separate them into separated sheets regarding the date, please find my code and advise

```
       List<Excelvo> excelvos = null;
       String strDate = "28-02-2021";
       String strToDate = "28-03-2021";

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        try {
            excelvos = ExcelDao.getInstance().getShabanCodes(100, strDate, strToDate);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CopyToExcel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        // Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); // new HSSFWorkbook() for generating `.xls` file
        //System.out.println(strDate.substring(0, 5));

        /* CreationHelper helps us create instances of various things like DataFormat, 
         Hyperlink, RichTextString etc, in a format (HSSF, XSSF) independent way */
        CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

        // Create a Sheet
        // for loop to create more than 1 sheet
        
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(strDate.substring(0, 5));
        // Create a Font for styling header cells
        Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();

        headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints(
                (short) 12);
        headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());

        // Create a CellStyle with the font
        CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();

        headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);
        headerFont.setBoldweight(headerFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        headerCellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_50_PERCENT.getIndex());
        headerCellStyle.setAlignment(headerCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);

        // Create a Row
        Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);

        // Create cells
        //for the table header.
        for (int i = 0;
                i < columns.length;
                i++) {
            Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(i);
            cell.setCellValue(columns[i]);
            cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
        }

        // Create Cell Style for formatting Date
        CellStyle dateCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();

        dateCellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
        dateCellStyle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        dateCellStyle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        dateCellStyle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        dateCellStyle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        headerCellStyle.setAlignment(headerCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);

        dateCellStyle.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        dateCellStyle.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
        dateCellStyle.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        dateCellStyle.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
        dateCellStyle.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        dateCellStyle.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
        dateCellStyle.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        dateCellStyle.setTopBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
        // Create Other rows and cells with employees data
        int rowNum = 1;
        for (Excelvo excelvo
                : excelvos) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);

            row.createCell(0)
                    .setCellValue(excelvo.getCode());

            row.createCell(1)
                    .setCellValue(excelvo.getSentDate());

            row.createCell(2)
                    .setCellValue(excelvo.getCampaign());

            row.createCell(3)
                    .setCellValue(excelvo.getMsisdn());
        }

        // Resize all columns to fit the content size
        for (int i = 0;
                i < columns.length;
                i++) {
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
        }

        //String excelFilePath = "D:/Excel/MyFirstExcel.xlsx";
        //FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
        // Write the output to a file
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("sugar sha3ban campaign 2021 code log 28 Feb - 30 Mar.xlsx");

        workbook.write(fileOut);

        fileOut.close();
```

I need to separate the data into multiple sheets regarding the date
the retrieved data: each month has data I want to separate this data to put each month with their data in a sheet?

Comment: You have create a `Sheet` already (`Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(...)`, you can create more of them... The separation of your data is something you have to do yourself.

Comment: There's no possible way to let it be created dynamically and be separated in the code regarding the date?

Comment: Sure there is, but you have to define that way yourself… There must be some code that separates the data by date and handles the sheet creation. That's your part, I guess ;-) I wouldn't create a single sheet containing all data and then separate the data afterwards. But I don't know your exect and complete requirements.

Answer (score 0):

By using [MemPOI](https://github.com/firegloves/MemPOI) you can simply execute different queries and bind them to different sheets, letting the db to apply the required filters. MemPOI will take care of the generation. Something like this:

```
MempoiSheet januarySheet = MempoiSheetBuilder.aMempoiSheet()
                            .withSheetName("January")
                            .withPrepStmt(conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE date = 'mydate'"))
                            .build();

MempoiSheet februarySheet = MempoiSheetBuilder.aMempoiSheet()
                            .withSheetName("February")
                            .withPrepStmt(conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE date = 'mydate 2'"))
                            .build();

MemPOI memPOI = MempoiBuilder.aMemPOI()
                            .withAdjustColumnWidth(true)
                            .addMempoiSheet(januarySheet)
                            .addMempoiSheet(februarySheet)
                            .build();
```